# Instruct ASP.NET to not indent option tags of the drop down lists

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET seemingly generates the drop down list options indented by 2 tabs.

Among a dozen drop downs on a page with up to 100 options in each of them, that bloats the pages by ~2 kb.

Is there any way to instruct ASP.NET page to generate the `option` tags without indent?

If that is not possible, is there an event to plug into where HTML is already rendered, but the final changes can be still done to it? (i.e. before Unload)

Comment: Use HTTP compression then this "bloat" will become even less significant then it already is.. you *could* register a custom control render, but too much effort for to little gain.

Comment: One way to do this would be to use a Control adapter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Joe: Would be a great answer! Thanks!